# what does it take for .snap package to be automatically updated from snap store?

Tags: ubuntu, iot, snapcraft

what does it take for .snap package to be automatically updated from snap store ?

1. is it some configuration on the ubuntu core.
2. whether .snap package (app) should have code to work with store and update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, at the time of this writing, on the desktop snaps are not automatically updated (they must be manually refreshed). This is a known bug and is being fixed. If that's why you're asking the question, keep that in mind :) .

To actually answer your question: snaps installed from the store are automatically updated when a new version is published in the store, in the same channel. Period. It's super easy-- you shouldn't need to do anything. To make this more clear, let's walk through an example.

Say you had snap `foo`, built with Snapcraft as `foo_1_amd64.snap`. You can run `snapcraft upload` to upload it to the store, or you can do it yourself by visiting [MyApps](http://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/). Once it passes the automated review, you can publish it into one or more channels (the one used by Snappy by default is `stable`, so that should contain your stable releases).

Now you can run `sudo snap install foo` and it'll install your newly published snap, version 1. Ignoring the known issue outlined above, if you publish another version of the `foo` snap in the same channel, you'll notice that eventually the installed `foo` is updated to the new version. I say "eventually" since updates are randomly staggered throughout the day.

Comment: that answer really helps. one more doubt i have after referring autoupdate @ https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/autoupdate/ is that, whether the setting on autoupdate impacts automatic updates to the snaps installed from store or is it only applicable to ubuntu-core components.

Comment: Ah, yeah I can understand where you're coming from there. Automatic updates apply system-wide (including non-ubuntu-core components), but whether or not automatic updates are ENABLED system-wide is controlled via the configuration of the ubuntu-core snap. Does that make sense? Note also that `snappy config` does not currently exist on the desktop-- something that will be added soon.